# Как с помощью selectonemenu заполнить два столбца в таблице?

Tags: java, java-ee, arraylist, jsf, primefaces

Заполняется лишь один столбец, не знаю как заполнить два, хэлп плз
Пробовал с помощью arraylist и hashmap, но не получается

jsf:

```
  <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5">
            <p:outputLabel for="console" value="Basic:" />
       <p:selectOneMenu id="console" value="#{cdiBean.onem}" var="onem" style="width:125px">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
            <f:selectItems itemLabel="#{onem.name}" itemValue="#{onem.name}"/>

            </p:selectOneMenu>
            </h:panelGrid>
```

bean:

```
   public class Products {
        long id;
        String name;
        long price;

    //getters and setters...
    }
```

cdi bean:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class CdiBean implements Serializable {
    List<Products> listOfProducts = new ArrayList<>();
    Products newProduct = new Products();
    List<Products> onem = new ArrayList<>();
List<Products> newProductsList = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Products> getOnem() {
        return onem;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Products products = new Products();
        products.setId(1);
        products.setName("asd");
        products.setPrice(100);
        listOfProducts.add(products);

        products = new Products();
        products.setId(2);
        products.setName("qwe");
        products.setPrice(20);
        listOfProducts.add(products);

        Products prod = new Products();
        prod.setName("hana");
        prod.setPrice(9);
        onem.add(prod);

        prod = new Products();
        prod.setName("ama");
        prod.setPrice(9);
        onem.add(prod);
    }



public void createNewListProducts() {
    listOfProducts.addAll(onem);

}

//getters and setters listOfProducts/onem/newProductList
}
```

Comment: Не уверен, т.к. `jsf` не использовал, но в строке `p:selectOneMenu id="console" value="#{cdiBean.newProduct.name}` Вы передаете один обьект, а нужно передавать список. Скорее всего `p:selectOneMenu id="console" value="#{cdiBean.listOfProducts}" var ="prod` а из него уже дергать Products `itemLabel="#{prod.name}" itemValue="#{{prod.name}" />`. Напишите, если помогло решить вопрос

Comment: да, понимаю что нужно передавать список, но не получается

Comment: Ну вот так, по моему примеру пробовали?

Comment: да, вообще не выводит список

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос с измененным кодом, чтоб посмотреть

Comment: вашим способом не получалось, я примерно накидал как по логике должно быть, метод create на кнопке

Answer (score 0):

Похоже на то, что вопрос неверно сформулирован - непонятно, что за столбцы. В примере `JSF`-страницы неверно определён выпадающий список, из-за чего в нём появляется только один статический элемент (`f:selectItem`), а динамический список `f:selectItems` не появляется. Подозреваю, что суть вопроса относится именно к этой проблеме. Ошибки:

1. `value` в `selectOneMenu` должно указывать на выбираемый элемент, а не на список
2. `var` в данном случае должен быть определён в `selectItems`, а не в `selectOneMenu`
3. В `selectOneMenu` не определён источник данных - атрибут `value`

Вот пример с исправлениями:

```
            <p:selectOneMenu id="console" value="#{cdiBean.newProduct}" style="width:125px">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue=""/>
                <f:selectItems itemLabel="#{onem.name}" itemValue="#{onem.name}"
                               var="onem" value="#{cdiBean.listOfProducts}"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: itemValue="#{onem.name}" тут немного не корректно будет. в меню указано что в value должен поместиться Product, а мы передаем только name.